# Extract function not working as I want in Oracle Db

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have tried many ways of getting the day,month and year in PLSQL but it keep throw me the error.

```
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
```

Here is the query I run (The mfgdate and receivingdate are timestamp(6) column, and the receivingdate has null value)

```
select 
           IC_MST_CodeDateData.mstid               AS mstid, 

    from   IC_MST_CodeDateData 
    where  ( ( IC_MST_CodeDateData.consprtydatecode = 'M' ) 
    and ( IC_MST_CodeDateData.mfgdatereqd = 0 ) 
    and ( EXTRACT(day from cast(( IC_MST_CodeDateData.mfgdate -  interval '5' hour )as DATE))  = extract(day from cast(( IC_MST_CodeDateData.receivingdate -  interval  '5' hour )as Date)) ) 
    and ( extract(month from cast(( IC_MST_CodeDateData.mfgdate - interval '5' hour )as DATE) )= EXTRACT( Month from cast(( IC_MST_CodeDateData.receivingdate - interval '5' hour )as DATE)) ) 
    and ( extract(year from cast(( IC_MST_CodeDateData.mfgdate - interval '5' hour )as DATE)) = extract(year from cast(( IC_MST_CodeDateData.receivingdate - interval '5' hour )as DATE)) )
```

I check the mfgdate column and there are no NULL value.

If anyone can help would be very appreciate!

Comment: What are the data types of `mfgdate` and `receivingdate`?

Comment: You compare year, month, day, thus `TRUNC(mfgdate - interval '5' hour) = TRUNC(receivingdate - interval '5' hour)` should be sufficient.

Comment: mfgdate and receivingdate are timestamp(6). And I just found out the receivingdate has null value.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit  is correct but even that can be reduced further to trunc(mfgdate) = trunc(receiningdate). There is no need get local time from UTC. If they are equal in one then  they are equal in any other providing the adjustment interval is the same.

Comment: @Belayer I fix it because our DBA using the to_date(1,'J') in Database.that function set time back to -4012 years old....... I used Substring on Timestamp and it is worked. Thanks for your help